# stan_betareg gets the error " Invalid stanfit object produced"?

Tags: r, rstanarm, betareg

I cannot run stan_betareg. Checked that all y variables are in hte proper support and updated the package. Still doesnt work? What else should I check?

Running

```
model<-stan_betareg(
linformula,
link=c('logit'),
data=train ,
model = TRUE,
x = TRUE,
y = TRUE,
contrasts = NULL,
weights = Insured.Acres,
QR=TRUE,
refresh=0,
prior= normal(0,2),
prior_intercept = normal(0,2)
)
```

linformula is defined using as.formula to be:

```
PercentLoss ~ LossRatio.11 + ZeroIndemnities.11 + LossRatio.15 + 
    ZeroIndemnities.15 + LossRatio.16 + ZeroIndemnities.16 + 
    LossRatio.41 + ZeroIndemnities.41 + LossRatio.51 + ZeroIndemnities.51 + 
    LossRatio.78 + ZeroIndemnities.78 + LossRatio.81 + ZeroIndemnities.81 + 
    LossRatio.91 + ZeroIndemnities.91 + prec + dday0C + dday10C + 
    dday30C + prec2 + weightCovLevel.84 + totalpolicies | totalpolicies + 
    weightCovLevel.84
```

All covariates are numeric

gets the error:

[1] "Error in sampler$call_sampler(args_list[[i]]) : Initialization failed."
[1] "error occurred during calling the sampler; sampling not done"
Error in check_stanfit(stanfit) :
Invalid stanfit object produced please report bug

RStanARM Version
2.21.3

R Version
4.2.1

Comment: It would be worth noting that you've filed a bug report, I started to go look for the site to tell you to do that. (note that data for a reproducible example are also linked there) https://github.com/stan-dev/rstanarm/issues/576

Comment: That was the bug report I filed, yep! Just checking if someone on here knew what was up